# Error in plot.new() : attempt to plot on null device

Tags: r, plot

I've recently upgraded my version of R to the newest version and it has resulted in an issue for graphing plots. I'm receiving an error that says:

> Error in plot.new() : attempt to plot on null device.

I've had no issues plotting on the older version of R, however there was an issue with R freezing whenever I would try to fit a certain set of data.

Here's my code for reference.

```
 plot(x = 1)
 library(ISLR)
 fit <- lm(mpg ~ horsepower, data = Auto)
 plot(fit)
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
Error in plot.new() : attempt to plot on null device
 dev.off()
Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)
```

Comment: Are you running R on macOS?